# Mailserver troubles

Tags: php, mail-server, hmail-server

Hey guys I'm trying to setup a mail server so I can send emails using my php webserver. I think I have it setup, but when I Try to send mail I get this error:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid. in C:\wamp\www\scripts\register.php on line 57
```

Here is my mailserver config in php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = admin@custombb.no-ip.org
```

And here is my send mail line of code:

```
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Error from log:

```
"TCPIP" 3584    "2012-03-15 14:56:20.609"   "TCPConnection - Posting AcceptEx on 0.0.0.0:25"
"DEBUG" 3584    "2012-03-15 14:56:20.609"   "Creating session 10"
"SMTPD" 3584    10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.609"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 custombb.no-ip.org ESMTP"
"SMTPD" 3584    10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.609"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: HELO duncan"
"SMTPD" 3584    10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.609"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 250 Hello."
"SMTPD" 868 10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: MAIL FROM:<you@yourdomain>"
"SMTPD" 868 10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 550 The address is not valid."
"SMTPD" 3544    10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 3544    10  "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"DEBUG" 4080    "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "Closing TCP/IP socket"
"DEBUG" 4080    "2012-03-15 14:56:20.625"   "Ending session 10"
```

What could be causing this? What is an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: its the mail function it self, what the the vales of $to and $headers.

Comment: Check your mail server logs for details on what addresses it saw; if you're lucky they reference the rules that your address violated.

Comment: the from address is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The mailaddress admin@custombb.no-ip.org returns with a rejection.

Try: http://www.gaijin.at/olsmailcheck.php
and this said your error-log to: 'SENT: 550 The address is not valid.' look here for example: 
http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_error_messages_smtp

Try an alternative Mail-Account.